# Please Help! Need javascript dropdown filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I have this site: [GebrAuto](http://gebrauto.blogspot.com/) does anyone have an example of a javascript searchbox with a dropdown filter? so for example i'm looking to create a searchbox for my site and allow users to either search: "Current Category" or "Whole Site". I could create a combobox and place it next to the input box but i'm trying to see if there is a fancier js way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Select2: https://select2.github.io/

It'll create a searchable Dropdown and all you have to do is bind it to a `select` element.